# New action 'preview' in CRUD controller with Easy Admin

Tags: action, easyadmin, symfony6

I want put a preview button in the edit page of my ArticlesCrudController.
I think i respected all the step but i've always this error : Warning: Undefined array key "ea".

here it is m code :

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

class ArticlesCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
//...

    /** la méthode configureAction permet de mettre en place le bouton ainsi que son action */
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $preview = Action::new('previewArticle', 'Prévisualisation')
            ->displayAsButton()
            ->linkToCrudAction('previewArticle');

        /** J'affiche le bouton sur la page d'édition de l'entité article */
        return $actions
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, $preview)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_NEW, $preview);
    }

    /** Mise en place de la méthode previewArticle qui doit envoyer vers le template de prévisualisation */
    public function previewArticle($entityId, ArticlesRepository $repo): RedirectResponse
    {
        $article = $repo->find($entityId);
        if (!$article) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Article not found');
        }

        return $this->render('site_diet/preview/preview_article.html.twig', [
            'articles' => $article
        ]);
    }
```

A this step i have correctly the button :) But it doesn't ok :(
What is the problem please ?
I'm using easyadmin 4.7.0

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you resolved this or not but I had the same problem and just resolved it with removing displayAsButton() from the action.
It should be:

```
$preview = Action::new('previewArticle', 'Prévisualisation')
            ->linkToCrudAction('previewArticle');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer :

First, add the action with an overwritting of the method configureActions() :
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
$preview = Action::new('preview', 'Prévisualisation')
->linkToCrudAction('previewArticle');

```
    $actions
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, $preview)
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_NEW, Action::SAVE_AND_CONTINUE);

    return $actions;
}
```

Second, write previewArticle() method like this :
public function previewArticle(AdminContext $context)
{
$article = $context->getEntity();
$previewArticle = $article->getInstance();

```
    return $this->render('site_diet/preview/preview_article.html.twig', [
        'articles' => $previewArticle,
    ]);
}
```

And it works very well :)